# Populate tree view

Tags: treeview

A have a dataframe with almost 70 columns. One column ['Level'] represents a hierarchically level.
With the code, nesting is not correct as 2.3.1 should be child of 2.3

[Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M91Tj.png)

Also I want to show data without to define each of columns in item.

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTreeView
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QAbstractItemView
from PySide6.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Level": [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4],
    "Status": ["-", "-", "E", "-", "-", "V", "-", "-", "V"],
    "Item": ["Level 1.0", "Level 2.1", "Level 2.2", " Level 2.3", "Level 2.3.1", "Level 2.4", "Level 2.4.1", "Level 2.4.2", "Level 2.4.2.1"]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

class TreeViewExample(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("TreeView-Data")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        self.treeview = QTreeView(self)
        self.treeview.setGeometry(50, 50, 700, 500)
        self.treeview.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)

        self.model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.treeview.setModel(self.model)

        self.populate_treeview()

    def populate_treeview(self):
  
        level = df['Level']
        items_by_level = {level: [] for level in level}

        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            item = QStandardItem(f"{row['Item']} (Status: {row['Status']})")
            items_by_level[row['Level']].append(item)

        for level in level:
            if level == 1:
                parent_item = self.model.invisibleRootItem()
            else:
                parent_item = items_by_level[level - 1][-1]

            for item in items_by_level[level]:
                parent_item.appendRow(item)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TreeViewExample()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```